# Passing sensitive data from C to Java

Tags: java, c, security, ipc

I am developing a C program which has to invoke a `Java` `main()` through `popen()` and send some data as command line arguments to it. However, there is some more data that needs to be sent to `Java` from `C` which is somewhat sensitive in nature (not the password kinds, though).

I am trying to see if there is any other option besides encryption to send this extra data from C to Java. I am trying to avoid overheads as data is not as sensitive so as to go for encryption, but I am open to any suggestion in this regard.

I cannot send this extra data through popen() as it will be visible through `ps -f`.

Similarly, using sockets does not seem viable because `tcpdump` can reveal that information too.

I considered using shared `mem (/dev/shm)` but that too can be viewed or use hidden files. Since, this also comes with overheads of creating files for every invocation, I am not fully in favor.

I looked at `ANON` file mapping but I guess, I cannot use it in Java side. 
Similarly, using `fmemopen()` reference does not seem be possible through Java.
Would `FIFO` pipes be a better option? Or can they also be read easily?

If I just resort to plain `mmap()` and write data to it (*not create it on disk - no O_CREAT in open call*), and not perform `msynch` would it remain entirely in memory? Can I then read in Java from it?

Is encryption my only option or am I missing something basic?

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282195/passing-data-from-c-to-java) discusses sending plain data over to Java from C.

Comment: The data can only be visible via `tcpdump` if the untrusted user is privileged (i.e., root). If you are trying to block root from accessing the information, you are in *real* trouble.

Comment: Go for encryption, I would suggest.

Comment: What about stdin/stdout?

Comment: Problem with any technique is that you are protecting yourself from a privileged user that already has access to the machine and is logged in. If you aren't going to trust existing auditing mechanisms to prevent the user from snooping a socket connection, then you are stuck, Any solution will be snoopable by the superuser with the appropriate tools (e.g., `gdb` attach to your process).

Comment: @jxh - I'd agree about tcpdump. I treat sockets as well as hidden file approaches to be similar. Both incur similar overheads.

Comment: @AshayThorat - Where do you suggest the encryption key be stored & how should it be protected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a user can use tcpdump, the user has root access. This user can also put a debugger on your Java program and see exactly what it does, even before the data is encrypted. The only way to achieve what you want is to go for total obfuscation techniques and encryption, like the Skype client does<sup>1</sup>.

But since you at the same time say, that the data is not *that* sensitive, it seems like overkill. Maybe a simple obfuscation technique so the output is not visible to a casual observer is enough? (Like [Rocker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18952833/193892) suggested.) Either that, or make sure the "untrusted" user does not have root access on the server where your system (Java + C program) runs.

A decent<sup>2</sup> obfuscation and probably a good trade-off, would be to use mmap() (or System V [shared mem](http://fscked.org/writings/SHM/shm-5.html)) to communicate.

If you use the [MAP_LOCKED](http://www.thelinuxblog.com/linux-man-pages/2/mmap) option and [MAP_ANONYMOUS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), the memory area will not end up on disk. [MAP_LOCKED](http://www.thelinuxblog.com/linux-man-pages/2/mmap) prevents it from going to swap, and [MAP_ANONYMOUS](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) tells the OS to not use a backing file.

Also, did you consider using [JNI](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jni/index.html) instead, to access your C code? That way, your C code would be part of the Java process and the distrusted user would need a debugger to spy on what was going on.

---

<sup>1 *The Skype client is not impossible to spy upon, but very hard. This comes at a price though, it must be extra costly maintain that code while keeping the obfuscation techniques intact. It is also an arms race between the Skype coders and the researchers trying to figure out how it works.*</sup>

<sup>2 *It would stop me for a long while, I would have to read up a LOT on debugging techniques before I figured out what was even happening, and then a lot of work to figure out what was "talked" about between the two programs. A more talented person would probably decipher everything in at most an afternoon.*</sup>

Comment: So, something like  int prot = (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE); would be good enough? Not sure I understood how would I ensure that there is no file also backing it. Can you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: @Sumit, I updated answer to mention MAP_ANONYMOUS. For MAP_LOCKED to succeed, I imagine the memory area should not be too large.

Comment: Yes, but I think Java cannot read an ANONymously mapped file. That was an option I considered earlier. I would like to be corrected in case ANON mapped files can be read in Java.

Comment: @Sumit, Java "can" if you do it from JNI with C.

Comment: Sure Prof. Falken. 
Doing Java --> C with JNI has been documented well enough. I have also seen references of C --> Java invocation with JNI somewhere. Will explore it more.

Comment: @Sumit, in this case, I mean do just enough Java -> JNI to read/write the memory area which the C program also can access. Nothing very fancy.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to avoide intensed user to use data is encr. If you still want other mechanism than one way is -
If your data contains mixture of multiple data types i.e. int float char* etc. than convert data into binary format. binary data is not readable by user directly. But intensed user if he want can convert back to original format. Its kind of encr only user can decr it if they want.

but this is not recommended. Use some standard encr.

Comment: Where will the encryption key be stored?

Comment: standard encr mechanism contains encoder and decoder. before sendind encode data send it.  recver end recv, decode and use it. If you are using your own encr and decr than sending and recv part is in your hand. you can have your own string format after that pass key so at recv end whenever that particular string will come after that string is your key to decrypt. I hope this will ans your queries

Comment: No it doesn't. First of all, Encoding and Encryption are two totally different things. In the answer, you refer to Encryption (I assume encr means encryption), in the comments you talk about encoding. 2nd thing, what exactly is meant by 'standard encr mechanism'. Whatever it is, where is the encryption key stored. Also if the key is sent along with the encrypted data, then anyone who gets the encrypted data can decrypt it.

Comment: yeah I mean encription. In general enc key is send along with data only but at particular location in side packet. That location is known by you only.

Comment: The location can be cracked in 5 minutes by anyone seriously wanting to do so by checking a few packets. Using obfuscation is far better than using this kind of insecure encryption.

Comment: yeah I mean encription. In general enc key is send along with data only but at particular location in side packet. That location is known by you only. I would suggest you refer broadcasting packets in DVBTCS. Obseerve PAT, PMT, EMM It will explain how encr will work in setupbox in detail which ca guied you your enc methods